# FuelPHP orm relation with multiple foreign keys

Tags: orm, fuelphp

I've just started using FuelPHP for my application and been stacked in a orm relation settings. 
I have the following 3 tables and want to display project list with department user names using the projects model.
But I cannnot figure out how to set the relations with orm relations.

How do you this relation using $_belongs_to, $_has_one, $_has_many, or $_many_many?

What I want to do is just like the sql 
    "select *, departments.name, users.name from projects
    left join departments on projects.department_id = department.id
    left join users on projects.user_id = users.id"

```
### TABLE projects ###
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projects` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`department_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `department_id` (`department_id`),
KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `projects`
ADD CONSTRAINT `m_project_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `departments` (`id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `m_project_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);

### TABLE departments ###
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `departments` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

### TABLE users ###
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`login_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`nickname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`last_login_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I got the solution.
    `protected static $_belongs_to = array(
    'departments' => array(
    'model_to' => 'Model_Departments',
    'key_from' => 'department_id',
    'key_to' => 'id',
    'cascade_save' => true,
    'cascade_delete' => false,
    ),
    'users' => array(
    'model_to' => 'Model_Users',
    'key_from' => 'user_id',
    'key_to' => 'id',
    'cascade_save' => true,
    'cascade_delete' => false,
    ),
    );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest to remember:

A many-to-many relation uses `$_many_many` in both models, and require a relationship table (aka join table or junction table).

For all others, one side is a `$_has_one` or a `$_has_many`, the other side is always a `$_belongs_to`. The model that contains the foreign key  is always the `$_belongs_to`.

In this example:
* user has_many projects, project belongs_to user
* departments has_many projects, project belongs_to departments

Comment: Thank you so much! I got the clue.